# I have a problem with passing array using service and subject

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs, subject

There're two components. One has products and on click each product push in empty array (addedToCart) in this component. Then using service and subject, from cart component I subscribe this array(addedToCart). But product start pushing after I go to cart page (using routing) and back to the product page.

**product component**

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  productList: Item[] = [];
  addedToCart: Item[] = [];
  constructor(private data: DataService, private cartDataServise:CartDataService) { }


  addToCart(product:Item){
    this.addedToCart.push(product)
    this.cartDataServise.sendCartData(this.addedToCart)
  }
```

**service**

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartDataService {
  private _cartData = new Subject<any>();
  myCartData$ = this._cartData.asObservable()
  constructor() { }
  sendCartData(cartData:any){
    this._cartData.next(cartData);
  }
}
```

**cart component**

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  cartItems:Item[] = [];
  constructor(private cartDataService:CartDataService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cartDataService.myCartData$
    .subscribe(
      cartData => {
        this.cartItems = cartData
        console.log(this.cartItems)
        console.log("vaxo")
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you have problem with? I can't understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using a subject, instead of a BehaviourSubject.

You cart component only starts subscribing when it is created (when you go to the cart page), by that time you have already pushed the item  in product component and the events done before reaching cart are lost, you can avoid this by using BehaviourSubject as it will give you the last pushed value by the product.

```
private _cartData = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>([]);
```